# Handle UI events with socket interaction purpose in multithreaded environment

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sockets

In my MVVM View some buttons show blink reaction to Server get status response.

A single button sends a sync socket request on mouse down and a sync socket request on mouse up with incremental ID on each message sent. On receive my client check if the response ID is the expected discarding the unexpected. Pressing multiple times a button in few millis increments the outgoing message ID too fast and the server responses are misaligned.

To fix this misalignment we set a lock, not only on the socket but on the button too (sob!) to prevent multiple clicks.

This seems to me a bad design practice, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve both the responsiveness and the message alignment.

Note: no code written because it seems to me a design practice more than a code template.

Edit: one of my ideas is to discard multiple mouse down events if the first is not served yet but it seems like WPF enqueues on its own the events raising them in FIFO way. I'm using EventToCommand and I can't see a `Handled` property to set.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved in a really simple but effective way.

The `EventToCommand` routes the `PreviewMouseDown` and the `PreviewMouseUp` events to `Execute_DownCommand` and `Execute_UpCommand`.

The `Execute_DownCommand`:

```
public void Execute_DownCommand()
    {
       DownWorkTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(SyncRoot))
                    {
                        return;
                    } // Don't let  multiple threads in here at the same time.

                    try
                    {
                      // Do Something
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Monitor.Exit(SyncRoot);
                    }
                });
    }
```

and the Execute_UpCommand:

```
public void Execute_UpCommand()
    {
       DownWorkTask.Wait(); // The release waits for the pressed work completion and starts without locking the UI

       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (!Monitor.TryEnter(SyncRoot))
            {
                return;
            } // Don't let  multiple threads in here at the same time.

            try
            {
                // Do Up Work
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(SyncRoot);
            }
        });
    }
```

The [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) acts like a lock, but allows a skip on multiple compulsive click without a queue.
I've used the [Task Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) because I need to complete the "Click" event sending in both halves a server request. On the network wrapper class I'm able to lock the socket allowing multiple button press without.

Hope it helps.